# terminal linux (Centos6) : how to exec command -> get PID in output + log file + without waiting?

Tags: linux, terminal, centos, stdout, stderr

I tried to run a command in the terminal that should have these features:

1) get in output only the PID without wait execution

2) save log stdout , stderr in a file

i tried with this :

```
echo $! | php test.php | tee log.txt &2>&1 /dev/null
```

but it returns me in output on the terminal both the stdout and stderr. then unfortunately we have to wait for the execution -.-

can someone help me on how to build the command?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [su] or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
(echo $! | php test.php | tee log.txt &2>&1 /dev/null) &
```

alternatively

```
 nohup (echo $! | php test.php | tee log.txt &2>&1 /dev/null) &
```

`nohup` runs a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty